# I need to identify a minifigure head piece

Tags: part-identification, minifigures

[image]

This is the part I need to identify

Answer (score 8):

That's [Minifigure, Head Medium Nougat Eyebrows and Contour Lines, Wide Grin Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb2191) on Bricklink. It was used just by one minifigure - [Newt Scamander](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=colhp17) from "Collectable Minifigures: Harry Potter Series 1".

[image]